# How to get hive current user name

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Currently i have logged in with the user **testuser1**.

I need to get the Current user in my hive query (Apache hive). But hive default current_user function is returning user as a 'HIVE' user.

select current_user() - hive

How can i get an current_user as - testuser1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `logged_in_user()` which returns current user name from the session state. This is the username provided when connecting to Hive. This function was added in Hive 2.2.0.

`current_user()` returns current user name from the configured authenticator manager (as of Hive 1.2.0).

Source: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

On Cloudera CDH 5.8 I get "Cloudera" when I run select current_user().

Comment: Thanks ravi... We are using hive version as Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.5.2. It's not having that function. Is there any other way we can get the logged in user ?

Comment: Not sure if it solves your issue but whoami can be added to the invocation of the sql e.g. : hive -e "select col, '`whoami`' from table1;